# Show jQuery date picker in jQuerymodal dialog

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-datepicker, jquery-dialog

There seems to be a problem with showing datepicker in modal dialog.

I'm using:

```
    $(".dpicker").datepicker({
        numberOfMonths: 2,
        dateFormat: 'd M yy',
        showButtonPanel: true
    });
```

to enable the datepicker on the given input field.

Please check the fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/ozjyu9k5/3/

It's working except while rendered in modal dialog.

Any suggestions to make the datepicker working in the dialog?

Please don't mark as duplicate as I searched the entire internet for a working solution and none of them seems to be working.

Answer (score 0):

Why not use a popup like [this one](https://jqueryui.com/datepicker/). You can see the full api here on the [official API page](http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/).

It would look like this:

[image: datepicker]

When you click in the input field it will show you the dialog like this

[image: datepicker open]

Your code would be something like this:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>jQuery UI Datepicker - Default functionality</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
  <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
  <script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css">
  <script>
  $(function() {
    $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker();
  });
  </script>
</head>
<body>

<p>Date: <input type="text" id="datepicker"></p>


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: yes, but my problem is that displaying Jquery UI datepicker in a Jquery UI modal window doesn't work. Otherwise it's working.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get the datepicker working in the fiddle by replacing your included jQuery UI JS and CSS files(External Resources) by the following:

//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css

//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js

Answer (score -2):

Try using JQuery UI datepicker. See below snippet (**[JsFiddle Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/chandansharma/3y1okden/)**):

**HTML Code:**

```
<p>HTML5 Date: <input type="date" placeholder="html5 date:" /></p>

<p><input id="Button1" type="button" value="Get DatePicker Value" title="Get DatePicker Value" /></p>
```

**Script**

```
// Insert placeholder as prefix in the value, when user makes a change.
$(".datepicker").datepicker({
    onSelect: function(arg) {
        $(this).val($(this).attr("placeholder") + arg);
    }
});

// Display value of datepicker
$("#Button1").click(function() {
    alert('call val(): {' + $("input").val() + '}');
});
```

Thanks,

**~Chandan**

Comment: This is not what i wanted. I need to get it displayed in a modal dialog, otherwise it's quite easy. Check my fiddle, already did what you've done.

Comment: @Liviuvalentyn or use Bootstrap to display datepicker inside modal, refer this link: http://codepen.io/Sinetheta/pen/Ftjwi

Comment: I need to do it with jquery UI modal dialog and datepicker, not Bootstrap.